# Python program for adding values in a dictionary

Tags: python

In the program given below, why 'None' is included in the output after running the program?

```
def total_takings(monthly_takings):
    list=[]
    for earnings in monthly_takings:
        list.append(monthly_takings[earnings])
    print(sum(sum(list,[])))



test1= total_takings({'January': [54, 63], 'February': [64, 60], 'March': [63, 49], 'April': [57, 42], 'May': [55, 37], 'June': [34, 32], 'July': [69, 41, 32], 'August': [40, 61, 40], 'September': [51, 62], 'October': [34, 58, 45], 'November': [67, 44], 'December': [41, 58]})

print(test1)
```

Comment: `total_takings` returns nothing, means it returns `None`. That's what you're printing.

Comment: change: `print(sum(sum(list,[])))` to: `return sum(sum(list,[]))` or simply remove the last line (that prints test1)

Answer (score 0):

`total_takings()` doesn't explicitly return anything, therefore it returns `None` by default.